# Selecting and Displaying mysql data through hidden form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having trouble displaying my selected data through MYsql. I have values already stored in the fields in my database and when the user clicks the submit button and the review of the selected movie should populate but its not.

Here is my code for the form in php.

```
    echo "<tr><td>".$utitle."</td><td>".$ucategory."</td><td>".$ulength."</td><td>Thumbs up</td>t<td></td>";
    echo '<form action = "videos.php" method="POST">';
    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='read' value=".$uid."><input type='submit' value='Read the Review' name='read'></td></tr></form>";
```

And here is my code when the button is clicked.

```
if(isset($_POST['read'])){
    $readReview = "SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id='$_POST[read]'";            
    $read = $con->query($readReview);
    if($read->num_rows>0){
        while($row=$read->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "Review:".$row['Review']."<br/>";
        }
    }
$read->close(); 
};
```

Thanks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: both your hidden and submit bear the same name attribute. I'd call that a conflict. Plus, it's discarding the first attribute, being the hidden one.

Comment: Oh man, you are the best. I can't believe I missed that especially when my other forms were different values for the name attribute. You helped relieved my headache.

Comment: Hopefully, user isn't supplying a value such as **`1' OR '1'='1`**, or something more nefarious, like **`Robert'; DROP TABLE MyVideos; --`**.  [**OWASP SQL Injection** https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: You're welcome Steve. Now someone's overbound my comment with an answer *sigh*. Oh well, what can you do ;-)

Comment: as steve hurries to backup his videos

Comment: @steve I decided to put my comment to an answer, including a few more things in there, should you wish to accept it. The choice is yours. Although not obligatory, this will inform the community that a solution was found. Otherwise, the question will remain as open.

Answer (score 4):

Putting my comment to an answer.

Both your hidden input and submit button bear the same name attribute. I'd call that a conflict. Plus, it's discarding the first attribute, being the hidden one.

Also, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['read']);
$readReview = "SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id='id'";
```

- Sidenote: `$_POST['read']` will need to be changed to the name attribute you'd of given to the hidden input.

Yet, prepared statements are the way to go here.

- Remember to rename your hidden input to something else of your choice.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Object oriented style

```
string mysqli::escape_string ( string $escapestr )
string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr )
```

Procedural style

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

Comment: To emphasize this point again... **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders** is the way to go. Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` addresses part of the problem, but some code patterns can still be vulnerable to SQL Injection. (+1 Fred -ii-) Your notes and remarks are spot on, as usual.  (I think the sql text should be `... id='$id'` nes pas?

Comment: @spencer7593 Indeed you're right and I see you have taken care of that in your answer, also being spot on, upvoted yours as well, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

In the code, this line:

```
$readReview = "SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id='$_POST[read]'";
```

the single quotes are missing around `read`. The single quotes appear as we expect them here:

```
if(isset($_POST['read'])){
                ^    ^
```

But beyond adding single quotes, the code is **vulnerable** to **SQL Injection**.

Use **prepared statement** with **bind placeholder**. Assuming that `id` column in `MyVideos` is character type:

```
  if(isset($_POST['read'])){
      $readReview = 'SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id=?';
      $sth=$con->prepare($readReview);
      $sth->bind_param('s',$_POST['read']);
      $sth->execute();
      $sth->bind_result($review);
      while($sth->fetch()){
          echo "Review:".htmlentities($review)."<br/>";
      }
      $sth->close();
  }
```

To make the pattern more clear, the code example above doesn't check the return from the `prepare` or `execute`. We'd really want to check if the return from `prepare` is FALSE, we don't want to call `bind_param` or `execute` on that.

If `id` column is integer type, then replace `'s'` with `'i'` (as the first argument in the `bind_param`.

The use of `htmlentities` assumes that the contents of the `Review` column does not contain any HTML markup that should *not* be escaped/encoded.

Answer (score 0):

submit and hidden field is same (not sure check it by changing)

change query:-

```
$readReview = "SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id='". $_POST[read] . "'"; // If id is varchar type or

$readReview = "SELECT Review FROM MyVideos WHERE id=$_POST[read]";  // If numric type
```

Comment: that shouldn't matter. MySQL will differentiate between both. The important thing about passing an integer is that the column type must match.